# Numero de columna de un DataSet c#

Tags: c#, dataset

Estoy manejando datasets en c#, necesito obtener el numero de las columnas, pero en este caso de una columna seleccionada o actual, que me devuelva su posicion o el numero de columna que es, alguien que pueda ayudarme.

```
DataSet ds = new Dataset;
int x = 0; int i = 0;
x = ds.Tables[0].Columns[i]["ColumnaActual"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes recorrer la columnas de `DataSet` con un `foreach`, y obtener la posición (en base 0) de la Columna con `Ordinal`, un ejemplo:

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        int x = 0; 

        foreach (DataColumn column in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
        {
            x = column.Ordinal;
        }
```

Comment: Gracias amigo , me funciono muy bien con el metodo ORDINAL, saludos.

Comment: @JuanDanielAlmeydaCalapiz: Estupendo!. Recuerda siempre valorar las respuestas que te han ayudado a solucionar tu pregunta, y marcar el check verde al lado de la respuesta que te ha solucionado la pregunta, con eso estarás colaborando con la buena salud de este sitio. Gracias.